# Hubot get flowdock thread details (thread id & first message in thread)

Tags: coffeescript, hubot, flowdock

I'm trying to write a small coffeescript for hubot that gets the first message in a thread and posts it to an external script.
I can get the flow id and user id info from the msg object but can't seem to find any object that contains the thread info (messages inside & thread id).
How can I get that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chat messages and messages that are created through the [messages API](https://www.flowdock.com/api/messages) have a thread_id and the thread's messages can be retrieved from `/flows/:organization/:flow/threads/:thread_id/messages`

However Flowdock has older type of messages, that are still created by integrations using the [deprecated push API](https://www.flowdock.com/api/push). These messages don't have a thread specified. Instead the comments to those messages are retrieved by finding messages with the tag `influx:{message_id}` e.g. `/flows/:organization/:flow/messages?tags=influx:123456`

However this older type of threading will not be supported in the future and all messages will have a thread_id.